# how to splitting a large array into smaller arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I need to split this array as smaller new arrays  based on the row of index

```
array(7) {
  ["device_name"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [4]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [5]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [7]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [8]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
    [9]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
  }
  ["device_description"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Ajtjv"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Gynfq"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Gfkgl"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Yadgv"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Obvlf"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "Anmag"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "Zeypc"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Rdeve"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "Iwxdd"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "Ciloy"
  }
  ["device_url"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [2]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [3]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [4]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [5]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [6]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [7]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [8]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
    [9]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example.com"
  }
  ["device_ip4"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Dnjon"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Wnthd"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Ybhmq"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Dqojf"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Pvdiv"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "Qobbu"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "Bvnic"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Xezcs"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "Jliql"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "Lbbcv"
  }
  ["device_ip6"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Haddj"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Vodto"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Roboi"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Lyuvq"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Zniny"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "Mmohr"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "Dwylp"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Bneop"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "Aojdn"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "Dxtvy"
  }
  ["device_username"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [2]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [4]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [5]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [6]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [7]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [8]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
    [9]=>
    string(26) "bhills_2852@mailinator.com"
  }
  ["device_password"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Xkazi"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Dwvso"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Mdjxp"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Pnnna"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Cwtko"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "Dchoh"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "Paltd"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Igzyo"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "Ubaio"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "Goiue"
  }
}
```

I need this array  to be new arrays like this array

```
array(7) {
[device_name]=>
    string(13) "Beverly Hills"
 [device_description]=>
  string(5) "Trmqv"
 [device_url]=>
  string(22) "http://www.example.com"
  [device_ip4]=>
  string(5) "Rfxsi"
 [device_ip6]=>
  string(5) "Lcjui"
[device_username]=>
  string(26) "bhills_0704@mailinator.com"
[device_password]=>
  string(5) "Ilhdz"
}
```

Hello I need to split this array as smaller new arrays  based on the row of index

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried so far and how has it failed? Post the code you have tried so far. Otherwise, no one can help you.

Comment: make new array and fill it in loop by values of original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic solution that does not need you to hard-code the keys:

If your original data is in `$devices`:

```
$device=array();
foreach($devices as $key=>$values) {
    foreach($values as $index=>$value) {
        $device[$index][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Output is in `$device` (singular).

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one , the problem solved  with  array_map

```
    $devices = array_map(null,
                $device['device_name'],
                $device['device_description'],
                $device['device_url'],
                $device['device_ip4'],
                $device['device_ip6'],
                $device['device_username'],
                $device['device_password']
            );

dd($devices);
```